# Evaluate lookup for known object

Tags: django

I have a filter along these lines:

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def joinable(self, current_time):
        query = Q(join_time__lte=current_time) & Q(end_time__gte=current_time)
        return self.filter(query)
```

So, given a time, return the events that you could join. I'd also like to add a `can_join` method to events:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    def is_joinable(self, current_time):
        return self.join_time <= current_time & self.end_time >= current_time
```

But I'd like to avoid duplicating the logic here (the actual logic is a little more complicated and will likely change). Is there a way in `is_joinable` to evaluate the query and determine if `self` would pass it? Or can I write both methods on top of some other method? Obviously I could do something like

```
query = Q(id=self.id) & joinable_query
return Event.objects.filter(query).exists()
```

but that seems a pointless extra database query for a record that I already have at my fingertips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [query expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) to do that calculation on the database and annotate the result as a boolean field, then filter on that field.

Something like:

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.annotate(
            joinable=Case(
               When(start_date__lte=now, end_date__gte=now, then=Value(True)),
               default=Value(False),
               output_field=models.BooleanField()
         ))
```

Now you can filter on `Event.objects.filter(joinable=True)`, and each Event object will always have a `joinable` field with the value True or False.

(Note, since that field is calculated by the database, if an event changes its joinable status while it's in memory - either because you change the dates explicitly, or because the dates fall due - the joinable field won't be updated. In practice this shouldn't be much of a problem.)

Comment: This is very interesting, but is tied very tightly to "now." So if during the life of the object it changes state (because time marches on, and these objects are used by celery tasks that are very long lived), it won't update. I've been avoiding letting the model ever look at "now" on its own because it makes unit tests so fragile; which is why I pass in the current_time to the is_joinable function. Still very interesting approach, though. (Maybe long-lived model objects are a problem anyway since they might change in other ways behind my back.)

Comment: Yes, I noted that in my answer. I don't see how there's an alternative: either you calculate the value in the database as part of the query, or you have it as a Python method only, or you duplicate the logic.